# Out of bounds exception printing in for loop less than arraylist size in java

Tags: java, for-loop, printing, indexoutofboundsexception

even though I clearly specify in the for loop that I want it to print until arraylist.size, the terminal returns an OutOfBounds Exception

```
public static void PrintPlayList() {
        int lengthsongs = songs.size();
        int lengthadds = adds.size();
        int amountadds = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lengthsongs; i++) {
        playlist.add(songs.get(i));
        if (amountadds < lengthadds) {
            playlist.add(adds.get(amountadds));
            amountadds++;
        }
    }

    int lengthplaylist = playlist.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthplaylist; i++) {
        System.out.println(songs.get(i).toString());
        System.out.println(adds.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

> And this is what the compiler returns: How is it possible? How can I fix it?

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 18, Size: 18
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Main.PrintPlayList(Main.java:153)
    at Main.Interface(Main.java:55)
    at Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Comment: Which line is the 153 ? because get() is called 3 times

Comment: @azro Line 153 is ; `System.out.println(songs.get(i).toString())`

Comment: Print songs.size() and adds.size() would have solve your problem in a few seconds, next time think about it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < lengthplaylist; i++) {
        System.out.println(songs.get(i).toString());
        System.out.println(adds.get(i).toString());
    }
```

`lengthplaylist` can be larger then `lengthsongs` in your code. And you're using for loop to go from 0 to `lengthplaylist` instead of `lengthsongs`.

You should also give attention to `adds.get(i).toString()` because for this to execute all the lengths must be same.

You may just use different variables in your loop for them like this:

```java
for (int i = 0,j=0; i < lengthsongs && j<lengthadds; i++,j++) {
        System.out.println(songs.get(i).toString());
        System.out.println(adds.get(j).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a debugger, you should see that the `playlist` has more elements than either `songs` or `adds` as it is the sum of these (though not quite) This error is produced at runtime not compile time.

The simplest solution is

```
public static void printPlayList() {
    playlist.clear();
    playlist.addAll(songs);
    playlist.addAll(adds);
    playlist.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

or just

```
public static void printPlayList() {
    songs.forEach(System.out::println);
    adds.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The list `playlist` is not initialized inside `PrintPlayList()`, so it might contain elements before. 
In this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lengthsongs; i++) {
    playlist.add(songs.get(i));
    if (amountadds < lengthadds) {
        playlist.add(adds.get(amountadds));
        amountadds++;
    }
}
```

you add all elements of `songs` to `playlist`, so `playlist` has at least as many elements as `songs`, but does it contain more? I don't know but you can find out by debugging.  
The same applies to the list `adds`.  
Do they all have the same size? This loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lengthplaylist; i++) {
    System.out.println(songs.get(i).toString());
    System.out.println(adds.get(i).toString());
}
```

will succeed if they do have the same size or `playlist`'s size is less than the other 2 lists.

Answer (score -2):

ArrayList in Java is indexed from 0. You are accessing index 18, however your list is contains elements from 0 to 17.

Since you store your `songs` and `adds` in `playlists`, you can print them directly from the `playlist` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lengthplaylist; i++) {
    System.out.println(playlist.get(i).toString());
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that but how can I fetch only until 17 which is what I what to do?

Comment: @J.Doe make the length the number of elements in `songs` not `playlist`

Comment: I think songs and adds  list size are different ... First check that .